# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error after running compiled a.out

Tags: c++

I'm writing code that should replace choosen word in text to "*". Dont know that's work but when I'm running compiled file a.out there is Segmentation Fault error. Any help pls?

### bleep.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "functions.hpp"

int main()  {

  std::string word = "broccoli";
  std::string text = "I sometimes eat broccoli. There are three interesting things about broccoli. Number One. Nobody knows how to spell it. Number Two. No matter how long you boil it, it's always cold by the time it reaches your plate. Number Three. It's green. #broccoli";
  
  looking_for(text, word);
  
}
```

### functions.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void looking_for(std::string &text, std::string word);
```

### functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "functions.hpp"

void looking_for(std::string &text, std::string word)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        int m = i; // saving "i" value when it's equal to b 
        std::string tmp;
        int j = 0;
        if (text[i] == word[j])
        {

            while (text[i] == word[j] && j < word.size())
            {

                tmp.push_back(word[j]);
                i++;
                j++;

            }
            
        }
        if (tmp == word)
            {
                for (m; m < m + word.size(); m++)
                {
                    text[m] = '*';
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: while (text[i] == word[j] && j < word.size())
            {

                tmp.push_back(word[j]);
                i++;
                j++;

            } You are not checking i here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps : Check for i too in the while condition and positions of i as in your case it kept on incrementing because you had used the same i to move forward.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


void looking_for(string &text, string word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length();i++)
    {
        int m = i; // saving "i" value when it's equal to b 
        int pos = i;
        string tmp;
        int j = 0;
        if (text[i] == word[j])
        {

            while (i<text.length() && j<word.length() && text[i] == word[j] )
            //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // i and j tested for validity before being used

            {

                tmp.push_back(word[j]);
                i++;
                j++;

            }

        }

        if (tmp.compare(word)==0)
            {
// in your case m is getting incremented and m is added up with word.length() which is the result for segmentation fault
                for (m=pos; m < pos + word.length(); m++)
                {
                    text[m] = '*';
                }
                i = i+word.length()-1;
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    // set i to the end of the word as that much is already checked
            }
        else{
            i = m; 
            //^^^^     // set it to the stored value as it has to start from the very next character for matching

        }
           // now i++ will automatically move i forward

    }
}

int main(){
    string word = "broccoli";
    string text = "I sometimes eat broccoli. There are three interesting things about broccoli. Number One. Nobody knows how to spell it. Number Two. No matter how long you boil it, it's always cold by the time it reaches your plate. Number Three. It's green. #broccoli";

    looking_for(text, word);
    cout<<text<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This is an answer, the other a comment. Answers are forever. Comments can be deleted at any time. This answer explains the problem and provides a solution. That's a good answer in my books. I'd edit in something to make the change you made more obvious, but that's about it.

Comment: Doesn't helped.. Still this same :((

Comment: Can you check it now, i forgot a minimal test case which i overlooked earlier.

Comment: Still... There is problem in if after while loop i think.. When i delete if statement file is running well

Comment: Can you check now? Also i ran it on my machine and it worked . Please see the reason for segmentation fault as well. Sorry for that many edits.. will make sure it won't happen in future.

Comment: Thx man! Now is perfect. And no problem, human is only human :D